# How can I create text field of incorrect guessed characters and a mystery word represented with underscores in Android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-edittext, game-engine, textview

I am new to Android game programming and started learning now. I would like to develop a game and my doubt is, how can I create edittext box with underscored format? For example, I am creating a game like this:

> Guess the word please _ _ _ _ _ ?

The user will try to fill the blanks. So, the correct word is apple.

And, the another way is can be like this also: the text field of incorrect guessed characters. For example:

> A _ _ _ E

So the user can easily guess the word after seeing 2 letters. So, probably answer is apple.

I just have read about Textwatcher but never I have worked on. So, using textwatcher can I make textview or edittext in this format ? That is , A_ _ _ E or _ _ _ _ _ ?

Using textwatcher can make the listener to listen to user inputs like beforetext changed and aftertextchanged. And, my doubt is should I replace some editextbox or textview position with "_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some thing smart here. You would probably like to handle those as well:

- A _ _ _ E
- _ P _ _ E

I suggest you to create an invisible input text above text field, and listen to user input, and modify the text filed as necessary.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that but how can I create that underscore in the position of invisible input text above textfield? Textview usually displays the input but how can I format this underscore fields in a textview or editext button?

Comment: Using textwatcher can make the listener to listen to user inputs like beforetext changed and aftertextchanged.. And, my doubt is should I replace some editextbox or textview position with "_"?

Comment: @Meena You should not edit the input text but only the text box